# How to insert data from 2 related tables into another 2 related tables using triggers?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with this one..

I have 2 tables that are related in a one-to-many relationship.

Table 1:

```
IDHeader(PK), name, number,..... so on
```

Table 2:

```
IDItem(PK), IDHeader(FK), names, numbers,... so on..
```

I've created 2 identical tables which serve as "backup" tables:

Backup Table 1:

```
Backup ID, IDHeader, name, number,..... so on
```

Backup Table 2:

```
Backup ID, IDItem, IDHeader, name, number,..... so on
```

(Note: I added `BackupID` so that would be a PK - FK relation in those backup tables. Or is it wrong? I can use the original relations from original tables? If so, how do I fill backup tables and keep the relations)

Now, the first 2 tables are almost identical to "backup" tables.. They only differentiate in few additional columns.

First 2 tables have relations, and they work fine (they are filled with data from SharePoint, but that's not important now).

I've written a trigger on Table1 that will copy the data from it to it's backup counter part.. So trigger that fills Backup Table 1 with data from Table 1..

I also wrote a trigger on Table2 that does the same thing, copy from Table 2 to Backup table 2..

My question is:

How to insert data from Table1 and Table2 into Backup Table 1 and Backup Table 2 so that those backup tables have relations as the Tables 1 and 2...

I am quite novice at SQL, so I'm interested if this kind of thing can be executed programmatically with triggers? Should it be 2 triggers for each table, or 1 trigger on Table 1 that will also fill data like: Table 1 -> Backup Table 1 | Table 2 -> Backup Table 2

I use GUID's for id's (I know, but not my idea)

Any comment, guidance or different approach or solution is welcome!!

Sorry for long text!

Comment: https://forums.sqlteam.com/t/automatically-replicate-or-duplicate-edits-and-inserts-from-one-table-to-another-identical-table-in-a-different-database/1545
Check here

Comment: SQL Server has views which are temporary tables.  SQL Server does not have links between tables.  So Joins are used to combine tables by column names.  So making a copy of a table (a new view) will not affect any relations.